# Modify sorting methods to sort in descending order

Tags: java, sorting, loops, for-loop

My question is if I wanted to change my sorting methods to sort in descending order what would have to be done? (Studying for a final)

My methods are as follows

```
    public void selectionsort(Comparable[] array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        int min = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
            if (array[j].compareTo(array[i]) < 0) {
                min = j;
            }
        }
        swap(array, min, i);
    }
}

public void bubblesort(Comparable[] array) {
    for (int poss = array.length; poss > 0; poss--) {
        for (int i = 0; i < poss; i++) {
            if (array[i].compareTo(array[i + 1]) > 0) {
                swap(array, i, i + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void insertionsort(Comparable[] array) {
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        Comparable temp = array[i];
        int poss = 0;
        while (poss > 0 && array[poss - 1].compareTo(temp) > 0) {
            array[poss] = array[poss - 1];
            poss--;
        }
        array[poss] = temp;
    }
}
```

I originally thought all that would need to be done is to change my compare to the opp of what is org was. But that does not seem to work.

Comment: What does "the opp of what is org was" mean?

Answer (score 2):

Change `array[j].compareTo(array[i]) < 0` to `array[j].compareTo(array[i]) > 0`.

And similarly flip `<` to `>` (and vice versa) in all your `compareTo` calls to reverse the order.

Answer (score 2):

Write a comparator function and use it instead of the `<` or `>` symbol. Then you can control which order it's sorted in from the comparator.

Also you can have a parameter in the comparator that decides which way it sorts, and then take that as user input. So the way it gets sorted can be controlled from the command line.

Comment: +0: +1 for recommending a Comparator, -1 for recommending to introduce a *state* in the Comparator. (The order should be reversed using http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverseOrder-java.util.Comparator- )

Comment: Well that's Java's way of doing things. I was more on the lines of trying to be functional and modify the comparator on the fly.

Comment: One could argue about the choice between `myComparator.setAscending(true)` and `myComparator = reverseOrder(myComparator)`, but in the end, one could probably say that it depends on the application case and intended usage...

Comment: True. Which in OP's case is the final he's studying for, which would make both options moot and may be equally useless. :)

Answer (score 0):

Create compareToReversed method that will return **-compareTo** result.
[Have a look here for inspiration](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)